# Spring cache and retrieve object without permanent store

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm building a stub in spring that does not have a permanent store but I want to be able to retrieve objects that have been sent to the stub.
Thus when the stub receives a payload I want to add it to a cache, and be able to get that object from the cache when queried.

I've read about spring's cache annotation implementation (@Cacheable ect.) but I can't work out how to implement this without a permanent store for the first call to that function.

I think an object can be put into the cache using:

```
@CachePut(value = "addressCache", key = "#customerId")
public Submission cache(Address address, String customerId) {
    return address;
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve this object from the cache using the key (customerId) without calling that original cache() function?

What would be a way to implement cache for what I need?

Comment: Why not just use a `Map` inside your stub?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [@Cacheable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html) annotation that does the look-up from the cache. [@CachePut](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CachePut.html) instead is invoked everytime to update the cache.